# GitHub Actions JavaScript Action Stuck at ImgBurn

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, building-github-actions

I made a GitHub action, which uses JavaScript to make a disk image with some commands and stuff. But now it is stuck at ImgBurn making the image using the command line, while it has the NOIMAGEDETAILS parameter. If someone could help me fix it. Here is the code:

```js
const core = require('@actions/core');
const github = require('@actions/github');
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const artifact = require('@actions/artifact');

async function run() {
  try {
    const path = core.getInput('path');
    const outputDir = core.getInput('output-dir');
    const filename = core.getInput('filename');
    const label = core.getInput('label');

    console.log(`path: ${path}`);
    console.log(`outputDir: ${outputDir}`);
    console.log(`filename: ${filename}`);
    console.log(`label: ${label}`);

    console.log('Doing prerequisites...');

    console.log('Installing ImgBurn...');
    await exec('choco install imgburn -y');

    console.log('Cloning repository...');
    const owner = github.context.repo.owner;
    const repo = github.context.repo.repo;
    const repoPath = '/path/to/repo'; // Replace with the path where you want to clone the repository
    await exec(`git clone https://github.com/${owner}/${repo}.git ${repoPath}`);

    console.log('Creating disk image...');
    const imgBurnPath = `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\ImgBurn\\ImgBurn.exe"`;
    const imgBurnArgs = `/MODE BUILD /BUILDINPUTMODE STANDARD /BUILDOUTPUTMODE IMAGEFILE /SRC "${path}" /DEST "${outputDir}\\${filename}" /FILESYSTEM "ISO9660 + Joliet" /VOLUMELABEL_ISO9660 "${label}" /VOLUMELABEL_JOLIET "${label}" /OVERWRITE YES /ROOTFOLDER YES /START /CLOSE /NOIMAGEDETAILS`;
    console.log(`Running ImgBurn with command: ${imgBurnPath} ${imgBurnArgs}`);
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(`${imgBurnPath} ${imgBurnArgs}`);
    console.log(`ImgBurn stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`ImgBurn stderr: ${stderr}`);

    console.log('Setting \'\\\' to \'/\'...');
    let diskOutputDir = outputDir;
    console.log(`The variable is set to '${diskOutputDir}'`);
    if (diskOutputDir.includes('\\')) {
      diskOutputDir = diskOutputDir.replace('\\', '/');
      console.log(`And now the variable is set to '${diskOutputDir}'`);
    }

    console.log(`Uploading disk image binary as an artifact...`);
    console.log(`Current working directory: ${process.cwd()}`);
    console.log(`outputDir: ${outputDir}`);
    console.log(`diskOutputDir: ${diskOutputDir}`);
    console.log(`Contents of outputDir:`);
    await exec(`dir ${outputDir}`);
    console.log(`Contents of diskOutputDir:`);
    await exec(`dir ${diskOutputDir}`);
    const artifactClient = artifact.create();
    const uploadResponse = await artifactClient.uploadArtifact(filename, [`${diskOutputDir}/${filename}`], diskOutputDir);

    console.log(`Pushing changes to Git...`);
    await exec(`git config --global user.name '${github.context.actor}'`);
    await exec(`git config --global user.email '${github.context.actor}@users.noreply.github.com'`);
  } catch (error) {
      core.setFailed(error.message);
  }
}

run();
```

What I tried:

1. Change variable type from Python to the batch one, to %VARIABLE%.